# Iterate through the dictionary using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, arraylist, generator

I'm trying to optimize the code when working with the Pandas in order to get a table with data read from csv-file.

This code works correctly, but it is quite cumbersome:

`pd_table = pd.DataFrame(`

```
    {
     10: [sheet['B' + str(item)].value for item in range(1,29) if sheet['A' + str(item)].value == 10],
     20: [sheet['B' + str(item)].value for item in range(1,29) if sheet['A' + str(item)].value == 20],
     30: [sheet['B' + str(item)].value for item in range(1,29) if sheet['A' + str(item)].value == 30],
     40: [sheet['B' + str(item)].value for item in range(1,29) if sheet['A' + str(item)].value == 40],
     50: [sheet['B' + str(item)].value for item in range(1,29) if sheet['A' + str(item)].value == 50],
     60: [sheet['B' + str(item)].value for item in range(1,29) if sheet['A' + str(item)].value == 60],
     70: [sheet['B' + str(item)].value for item in range(1,29) if sheet['A' + str(item)].value == 70]
      }
```

The result is a table with data

I reduced this code to this:

`values= [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]`

`pd_table = pd.DataFrame(`

`dict(zip(values, [[sheet['B' + str(item)].value for item in range(6,29) if sheet['A' + str(item)].value == 10]]*len(values))), index = ['10.08', '20.08', '30.08']`

`)`

Could you please tell how replace **10** in the construction
`...sheet['A' + str(item)].value == 10...` 
with "N", which would iterate numbers from the sequence 10, 20...70 from the list " values" ?

If I use `sheet['A' + str(item)].value == i for i in values`, then I get an error:
`local variable 'i' referenced before assignment`

Comment: what is `sheet`? please  provide a reproducible input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use a dictionary comprehension?

```
pd_table = pd.DataFrame(
  {val: [sheet['B' + str(item)].value for item in range(1,29)
         if sheet['A' + str(item)].value == val]
  for val in values},
  index = ['10.08', '20.08', '30.08']
)
```

Depending on the nature of `sheet` it might be possible to simplify this logic even further.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped a lot with solving this problem. I slightly optimized your code for `sheet` mine and it works correctly.